# Ceilometer or Healthnmon for measuring VM stats in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

I am looking to measure stats for VMs running in OpenStack environment. Stats would be like Uptime, CPU or RAM consumption just by that VM.

My understanding from reading the documentation is that Ceilometer and Healthnmon are for measuring the stats of the resources used on individual OpenStack nodes.

Is this true or can Ceilometer or Healthnmon be extended to capture monitoring stats from VMs as well?

Answer (score 0):

Ceilometer meters can be used to monitor the vm vital stats. In hea templates this is been used to monitor vm cpu utilizations and memory consumptions.

Comment: hi arijit, could you plese guide on how to create an application meter and publish the same in ceilometer. Links to bolg post, github code would be heartly appreciated